# imported data from excel to database wont copy all data from excel after getting null values

Tags: sql-server, excel

Please help me. suggest anyone who can help my problem please I'm begging you. I got this problem almost 1 week and I search on google for entire 4 days.
please help me with this problem.

when I importing the data from excel that looks like this:
[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgcYu.png)

I only get the row 3,4,5 and the rest in row 15 I only get the longer " -------- " symbol and the rest below is null.
I already search almost 5 days of the exact code that will copy all records or data what was written there and save to the database and the data type of the columns in my database are all `nvarchar(255)`.

and the code that I use in importing the data from excel to the database is like this:

```
public void ImportDataFromExcel(string excelFilePath, string user)
    {
        string ssqltable = "tmp_100_POEntry_SF";

        //string myexceldataquery = "select PONO,PODATE,PORECEIVEDDATE,DELIVERYDATE,PARTCODE,QUANTITY,UNITCOST,TOTALAMOUNT,STOCKS,INCHARGE,CLIENT from [Sheet1$]";
        string myexceldataquery = "select [PO NO],[PART CODE],QUANTITY,[UNIT COST],[TOTAL AMOUNT],STOCKS,[IN CHARGE],CLIENT,'5/3/2017' AS PODATE, '5/3/2017' AS PORECEIVEDDATE, '5/3/2017' AS DELIVERYDATE from [Sheet1$]";
        try
        {
            string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + excelFilePath +
            ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;hdr=yes;\"";

            string sclearsql = "delete from tmp_100_POEntry_SF where username = @username";
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();

            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(Common.connectionstring);
            bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[PO NO]", "PONO");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[PART CODE]", "PARTCODE");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("QUANTITY", "QUANTITY");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[UNIT COST]", "UNITCOST");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[TOTAL AMOUNT]", "TOTALAMOUNT");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("STOCKS", "STOCKS");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("[IN CHARGE]", "INCHARGE");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CLIENT", "CLIENT");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PODATE", "PODATE");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("PORECEIVEDDATE", "PORECEIVEDDATE");
                    bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("DELIVERYDATE", "DELIVERYDATE");

                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found in Excel data!");
            }
            dr.Close();
            string sclearsqls = "UPDATE tmp_100_POEntry_SF SET USERNAME = @username";
            SqlConnection sqlconns = new SqlConnection(Common.connectionstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmds = new SqlCommand(sclearsqls, sqlconn);
            sqlcmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
            oledbconn.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
    }
```

Comment: What I would try is using `IMEX=1` to tell the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/standard-alternative/.

Comment: thank you for your reply axel i will try this right away.

Comment: axel i got this king of error when i put the IMEX=1 in my code . it says "Could not find installable ISAM" what that mean?

Comment: thank you very very very very much axel i fixed the error that i got. and i got what i want. thank you very much for your suggestion.